# 2n Balls into 2 bins analysis using chernoff and chebyshev inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, balls-in-bins

Consider a balls and bins experiment with $2n$ balls but only
two bins.  Each ball is thrown independently into a bin chosen
uniformly at random.  Let $X_1$ be the random variable for the
number of balls in bin $1$ and $X_2$ for bin $2$.  It is easy to see
that $E[X_1] = E[X_2] = n$. We would like to have a handle on the
difference $X_1 - X_2$. Our goal is to prove that for any fixed
$\epsilon > 0$ there is a fixed constant $c > 0$ such that
$\Pr[X_1 - X_2 > c \sqrt{n}] < \epsilon$. By symmetry we can then
argue that $\Pr[|X_1 - X_2| > c \sqrt{n}] < 2 \epsilon$.

1.Compute the variance of $X_1$. Then use Chebyshev bound to
show that $\Pr[|X_1 - n| > c \sqrt{n}] \le \epsilon$ for suitable choice
of $c$ for a given $\epsilon$. What is the dependence of $c$ on $\epsilon$?

2.Use Chernoff bound to show that $\Pr[|X_1 - n| > c \sqrt{n}]
\le \epsilon$. You need to use the bound separately for
computing $\Pr[X_1 > n + c \sqrt{n}]$ and for $\Pr[X_1 < n - c \sqrt{n}]$.
What is the dependence of $c$ on $\epsilon$?

3.Using the preceding show that  $\Pr[X_1 - X_2 > c \sqrt{n}] < \epsilon$.

So, I have already compute the variance of $X_{1}$, and shown part (1) and part (2), but not sure how to use them to show (3)

Comment: Have you tried substituting in $X_2=2n-X_1$?

Comment: Oh, i see. I forgot that $X_{1} +X_{2} = 2n$